# Error in pygame.event.get() method

Tags: python, pygame

Why does `pygame.event.get()` give this error?

> error: video system not initialized

The code is functional but gives this error after performing the function.

```
pygame.event.get()
while not pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        pygame.quit()
    pygame.event.get()
```

The program quits but gives the above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing a call to `pygame.init` to initialize `pygame` modules.

For more information, please have a look at the [pygame introduction](http://pygame.org/docs/tut/intro/intro.html).

Comment: the init method is at the beginning of the game which I did not write here

Comment: Please update your question with enough code to reproduce the problem